# My cassandra v2.1.2, why use $nodetool -h ip stopdaemon command has ConnectException?

Tags: cassandra

I install cassandra v2.1.2 on suse linux.This is my cluster:

```
LAB2-13R-4-90:~ # sh /opt/apache-cassandra-2.1.2/bin/nodetool -h 10.6.1.90 status  
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.6.1.90  3.78 MB    256     ?       b7354225-9d59-4917-b3bf-b407dd4506b9  rack1
UN  10.6.1.54  3.77 MB    256     ?       132e8e4d-cd03-44a2-bd1a-99d5eef4c8b0  rack1
UN  10.6.1.55  123.23 KB  256     ?       cc4011fe-0f1e-4ffa-82ad-91143ba57002  rack1
```

It's exception when i use $nodetool -h node_ip stopdaemon command. But this node stop success.

Why i stop node has ConnectException?

```
LAB2-13R-4-90:~ # sh /opt/apache-cassandra-2.1.2/bin/nodetool -h 10.6.1.90 stopdaemon  
Cassandra has shutdown.
error: Connection refused
-- StackTrace --
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.PRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.close(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.close(RMIConnector.java:512)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.close(RMIConnector.java:452)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeProbe.close(NodeProbe.java:191)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool$NodeToolCmd.run(NodeTool.java:250)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.main(NodeTool.java:163)
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR; Nodetool tries to close it's connection to the server which you just stopped.

A+ explanation:

It's a bug in my opinion, but a completely harmless one. If you look at the last few lines of the stack trace you can tell what's going on and why the exception is being thrown:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        ...
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.close(RMIConnector.java:452)
this -> at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeProbe.close(NodeProbe.java:191)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool$NodeToolCmd.run(NodeTool.java:250)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.main(NodeTool.java:163)
```

The nodetool is composed of two classes, `NodeTool` and `NodeProbe`. *Roughly speaking* NodeTool runs all the commands, while NodeProbe handles more of the serialisation of various info that needs to be transfered from C* to the nodetool. The requiest of stopdaemon is executed, but before completing the request, `NodeProbe` tries to execute (or call or w/e) `close()`. The close function's purpose is to close the JMXConnection between the tool and *now shut down server*.

Comment: Thanks Lyuben! This helps a lot!